# DELL Inspiron lapton has CPU failure. What can I do?

Tags: cpu

My DELL Inspiron isn't starting at all. When I power on it beeps 7 times and I know this means CPU failure.

What can cause CPU failure? Is necessary to buy another CPU? Can CPU failure cause high temperature? e.g: CPU fan not working or no thermal paste on CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU Failures can be one of many things, none of which are particularly easy to fix.

There are a few things to check first before you give up all hope, like **is the CPU correctly mounted in its slot** (It might have worked itself very slightly loose)? Is the **Heat Sink** connected properly? These might not fix your problem, but they might give you an insight into why it failed. (Possible overheating)

The most common problem on an actual failed CPU is a **Dry Joint**, this is where one of the many soldered connections between your CPU and the motherboard, or the "legs" on the CPU, fails and **no longer provides a connection**, this can be delicately repaired by **re-flowing** with a heat gun and lots of patience, but I would definitely **not** recommend it to someone who is not electronically savvy with such things.

My best recommendation would be to send the laptop back to the manufacturer if it is under warranty, if not, your best option is to purchase and install an identical CPU (or an upgrade, if it's compatible with the slot on your motherboard). If this still doesn't fix the issue, I'd suggest sending it to a trusted laptop repair specialist.

Comment: *"or an upgrade, if it's compatible with the slot"* - laptop MoBo-s are designed for the bundled CPU and may be unable to provide power for a more powerful one. Swapping laptop CPUs isn't recommended.